# REST API's and PEGA

Tags: pega

I can see that you have some expertise with REST API's and PEGA. I would like to know if we expose web call using REST API's to PEGA, will we get all custom rules and all or we need to replicate the rules?

Regards,

Sudhanshu

Comment: Maybe you can clearify your question a little bit more - is Pega the consumer of a REST API or should Pega offer a REST API? Do you have sample requests and responses? Then you can use the Integration wizard like @jhoule86 pointed out.

Comment: Pega has some basic rest APIs for cases, assignments etc. Question is not clear on whether you want to consume some rest APIs in your pega application or expose some rules as rest apis ?

Comment: Pega is not treated as a Programming language . Stack overflow is all about Programming and relevant questions. Please use PDN for this.

Answer (score 1):

If you are consuming the REST API and will be using Pega as the REST client, you do not have to create the rules manually. There is an accelerator ("wizard") that will create the rules for you, based on an example request/response for the REST API.

Answer (score 0):

REST mean "Representational state transfer" in pega to create the REST , it provides widget by using widget we can create it. Please visit the link for more updates:

https://myknowpega.blogspot.com/2019/04/pega-81-application-development.html

Answer (score 0):

Since your question is not entirely clear, let me specify for both options (i.e., connector and service). Besides, I am assuming you are using the latest version of PEGA

1. **Integrating Pega with an external service (via Connect-REST)**

This can be achieved using the integration wizard by navigating as specified below Configure -> Integration -> Connectors -> Create REST Integration

Documentation to achieve it step by step is listed here

https://docs.pega.com/data-management-and-integration/84/creating-rest-integration

2. **Pega Exposed as a service to external systems via Service-REST**

It is bit of a manual process involving creation of service packages, service-REST rules and the configuring the methods GET/POST/PUT/PATCH/DELETE and its corresponding responses.

Documentation on the same is available here as indicated below.

https://docs.pega.com/data-management-and-integration/84/service-rest-rules